# Change field type from "text field" to "integer"

Tags: entities

I have a field that is numerical in nature and it was setup as text field. The problem is that sorting by ascending, the number 111 comes before 20.

Answer (score 4):

One option could be to create another field, of integer format.

Then using PHPMyAdmin (or similar) copy the contents of the  field_data_field_FIELDNAME_TEXT_FIELD into your newly created field_data_field_FIELDNAME_INTEGER_FIELD.

If that works you can then delete the original text field.

Comment: This is probably the best way to do it, if you don't have to rely on the history (revision) information on fields, as that would be lost if you started using a new field. The alternative is to actually change the type of field in the database, which involves changing the structure and the configuration for the fields. While not impossible, the latter is definitely the more complex approach.

Comment: This looks like the simplest approach.

Comment: The revision table data should be copied as well.. You can use the command for copying the data -- INSERT INTO field_data_FIELDNAME_TEXT_FIELD  (<Fields Separated by Comma>) SELECT <Fields Separated by Comma> FROM field_data_field_FIELNAME_INTEGER_FIELD.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer:**
You could try and use the following module.
https://www.drupal.org/project/helper

The function that you are interested is called changeType() inside the FieldChangeHelper class.

The way to go here is implementing an update hook.
Things can vary in your implementation. Haven't tested this particular implementation. This is just a guideline. Assume your field is called test.
Put this snippet in a custom module. Run update.php . Flush caches (x2) and you're done. 
Regards.

```
/**
 * Change field_test field from textfield to integer
 */
 function mymodule_update_7001() {
 // Manual database changes to the field config table. Sometimes there is serialized data to take into account.
   db_query("UPDATE {field_config} SET type = 'integer' WHERE field_name = 'field_test'");
 // drupal internal function that takes care of changing the field's attributes
 db_change_field('field_data_field_test', 'field_test_value', 'field_test_value', array(
 'type' => 'integer',
 'length' => '10',
 ));  
//revision field
 db_change_field('field_revision_field_test', 'field_test_value', 'field_test_value', array(
 'type' => 'integer',
 'length' => '10',
 ));
 // Clear caches.
 field_cache_clear(TRUE);
```

}

Comment: I have created the module.. replacing the word test with "field_unit_number" wherever it appeared in your code. Enabled the module. Ran update.php, and cleared cache 2x.

However, this did not fix. maybe i did something wrong with the code. here it is: http://pastebin.com/eUZwYcEp

Comment: I will take a look and try to reproduce in the evening, for you. Meanwhile, you could create new field (integer) and compare the field_config table in phpmyadmin for differences (it might be int instead of integer or something like that)..

Comment: the type for the field_config table should be 'number_integer'. In general making these kinds of changes without knowing exactly what you are changing is a risky, risky business. If you absolutely need to do this, create an integer field and copy the values used for the new field.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me and its based on the previous answer but its tweaked with the right parameters. Using drupal 7.34

Keep in mind that this can only be achieved if you have no values in the field or you KNOW that all values are just numbers(integers in this case). Otherwise you have to do some data manipulation prior to changing the field type.

```
function MYMODULE_update_7001() {
  // Manual database changes to the field config table. Sometimes there is serialized data to take into account.
  db_query("UPDATE {field_config} SET type = 'number_integer', module = 'number' WHERE field_name = 'field_name'");
  // Text fields have an aditional column for format which number doest have. We drop those.
  db_query("ALTER TABLE field_data_name DROP field_name_format");
  db_query("ALTER TABLE field_revision_name DROP field_name_format");
  // Change all empty values to 0 otherwise we get an error.
  db_query("UPDATE field_data_name SET field_name_value = '0' WHERE field_name_value =''");
  db_query("UPDATE field_revision_name SET field_name_value = '0' WHERE field_name_value =''");

  db_change_field('field_data_name', 'field_name_value', 'field_name_value', array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'length' => 11,
    'not null' => FALSE,
    'default' => NULL
  ));

  //revision field
  db_change_field('field_revision_name', 'field_name_value', 'field_name_value', array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'length' => 11,
    'not null' => FALSE,
    'default' => NULL
  ));

  field_cache_clear(TRUE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today, but I cannot create a new field, too much business logic on that.

I did like [@mask-ota](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/157312/34320), but I had to add more code because some of the field settings are stored in a php-serialized form in field_config.data and field_config_instance.data fields.

So I ended like this:

```
function MYMODULE_update_7101() {

    // Manual database changes to the field config table. Sometimes there is serialized data to take into account.
    db_query("UPDATE {field_config} SET type = 'number_integer', module = 'number' WHERE field_name = '[FIELD_NAME]'");
    // Text fields have an aditional column for format which number doest have. We drop those.
    db_query("ALTER TABLE field_data_[FIELD_NAME] DROP [FIELD_NAME]_format");
    db_query("ALTER TABLE field_revision_[FIELD_NAME] DROP [FIELD_NAME]_format");
    // Change all empty values to 0 otherwise we get an error.
    db_query("UPDATE field_data_[FIELD_NAME] SET [FIELD_NAME]_value = '0' WHERE [FIELD_NAME]_value =''");
    db_query("UPDATE field_revision_[FIELD_NAME] SET [FIELD_NAME]_value = '0' WHERE [FIELD_NAME]_value =''");

    db_change_field('field_data_[FIELD_NAME]', '[FIELD_NAME]_value', '[FIELD_NAME]_value', array(
      'type' => 'int',
      'length' => 11,
      'not null' => FALSE,
      'default' => NULL
    ));

    //revision field
    db_change_field('field_revision_[FIELD_NAME]', '[FIELD_NAME]_value', '[FIELD_NAME]_value', array(
      'type' => 'int',
      'length' => 11,
      'not null' => FALSE,
      'default' => NULL
    ));

    // field_config.data serialized field
    $result = db_select('field_config', 'c')
        ->fields('c')
        ->condition('field_name', '[FIELD_NAME]','=')
        ->execute()
        ->fetchAssoc();
    $data = unserialize($result['data']);
    unset($data['settings']['max_length']);
    $num_updated = db_update('field_config')
        ->fields(array(
          'data' => serialize($data),
        ))
        ->condition('field_name', '[FIELD_NAME]','=')
        ->execute();

    // field_config_instance.data serialized field
    $result = db_select('field_config_instance', 'c')
        ->fields('c')
        ->condition('field_name', '[FIELD_NAME]','=')
        ->execute()
        ->fetchAssoc();
    $data = unserialize($result['data']);
    unset($data['widget']['settings']['size']);
    $data['widget']['type'] = 'number';
    $data['widget']['module'] = 'number';
    $data['widget']['active'] = 0;
    unset($data['settings']['better_formats']);
    $num_updated = db_update('field_config_instance')
        ->fields(array(
          'data' => serialize($data),
        ))
        ->condition('field_name', '[FIELD_NAME]','=')
        ->execute();

    field_cache_clear(TRUE);
}
```

You canfind useful [this site](http://unserialize.onlinephpfunctions.com/) to serialize/unserialize data field and compare it with an existing integer field.

Comment: do you have to put this in a .install file of a module?